# Try to get the right GET link which shows the good info in shoppingcart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ok here is my problem after months of searching over the internet.  I want to get the right link from jquery to take the right div and show them on the page. For now the files takes the root with GET

I got 2 files.

shopping_cart.php and jquery-oscart.js

```
jquery-oscart.js

     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
       url:  encodeURI($(location).attr('href')) + '&action=update_product&ajax=1',
      data: $('form[name=cart_quantity]').serialize(),
      async:false,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#content-body").html(data);
        //Hide_Load();
        //update_cart();
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });
    // Updating cart total
    //
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
      url:  encodeURI($(location).attr('href')) + '&action=update_product&show_total=1&ajax=1',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#boxcart-total').html(data);
            //Hide_Load();
            }
        });
  return(false);
});
```

The action:  `.attr('action')`

The div that show up should be #content_body from the shoppingcart file.

In the shoppingcart.php file there is an action that calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-oscart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

In normal state there is no problem.

here is my question.

When execute the files Firefox gives me the following rules:

```
POST domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2&action=update_product&ajax=1

GET domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2

POST domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2&action=update_product&show_total=1&ajax=1

GET domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2
```

instead of

```
POST domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2&action=update_product&ajax=1

GET domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2&ajax=1

POST domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2&action=update_product&show_total=1&ajax=1

GET domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2&show_total=1&ajax=1
```

In the GET. I miss &ajax=1 and &show_total=1&ajax=1

Something had to be changed in the jquery_oscart.js but I don't know where to change...

I tried the .load function with the right link but that's not a solution.

I hope someone can help me with this.

---

The original code is:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: encodeURI($('form[name=cart_quantity]').attr('action')) + '&ajax=1', 
 data: jQuery('form[name=cart_quantity]').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
   jQuery("#content-body").html(data); 
    //Hide_Load();
    //update_cart();

}
});
// Updating cart total

jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
url: encodeURI($('form[name=cart_quantity]').attr('action')) + '&show_total=1&ajax=1', 
   data: jQuery('form').serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#boxcart-total').html(data); 
        //Hide_Load();
        }
    });
```

return(false);
});

it gives the link:

domain/index.php&ajax=1

instead of

domain../index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart&Itemid=2&action=update_product&ajax=1

Could it be something with the 'form'? It seems it send me to index.php instead of  index.php?option=com_oscommerce&osMod=shopping_cart

Problem solved the ? option... link was hidden. With another file I get is showed. Now the POST links are fine. The problem I only got is the GET link.

It seems url: encodeURI($('form[name=cart_quantity]').attr('action')) + '&ajax=1',

Gets 2 links a POST en ea returning GET. The returning link missed the &ajax=1 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
url:  encodeURI($(location).attr('href') + '&action=update_product&ajax=1'),
```

(I put &action=blahblah inside encodeURI)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help. nothing changed. when I delete action=update_product& the GET rule disappear what could that be?

Comment: It looks like all of the requests should be POSTs.  Perhaps the user is clicking a button to activate the request but the button's default action (submit the form) is also happening?  The javascript that invokes the $ajax call should return false or preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be solved by adding + 'format=ajax' in the url

like:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: encodeURI($('form[name=cart_quantity]').attr('action')) + '&format=ajax'+ '&ajax=1', 
 data: jQuery('form[name=cart_quantity]').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
   jQuery("#content-body").html(data); 
    //Hide_Load();
    //update_cart();

}
});
// Updating cart total

jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
url: encodeURI($('form[name=cart_quantity]').attr('action')) + '&format=ajax'+ '&show_total=1&ajax=1', 
   data: jQuery('form').serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#boxcart-total').html(data); 
        //Hide_Load();
        }
    });
```